# AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null after nuget update

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5

After updating the nuget packages of my MVC5 application (that has been working correctly up until now) The Authentication manager which is used to verify my users Facebook login is now always returning null.

I'm developing my solution in visual studio 2012 and using the latest webtools.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

After googling around, I have discovered that the Facebook API has been changed, but there is no solution about how to get the nuget pacakages working with an MVC5 application. Please can anyone guide me on how to get this working again.

I have tried the following but the request coming back from facebook is always null.

Adding

```
<system.web><authentication mode="None" /></system.web> 
<system.webServer><modules><remove name="FormsAuthentication" /></modules></system.webServer>
```

Setting

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Response.Cookies.Append("OwinCookie", "SomeValue");
HttpContext.Response.Cookies["ASPCookie"].Value = "SomeValue";
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Remove("ASPCookie");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I found the answer.

I did the following to get it working

Logon to the developer portal, locate your application and do the following.

App details > App centered Listed Platforms > Select Yes for website